# Node.js (Express) POST form data on the next screen

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, express

My Current data flow goes as follows:

Page1 - User inputs data using a `<form>` and clicks '**Review**'.

Page2 - User can review data collected from the previous screen and clicks '**Send**'. The collected data is now sent to the backend via a POST request to an endpoint.

**My current express logic:**

On Page1, I use a `<form method="POST" action="/review">` and on `submit`, passing the form data to express route. As shown below:

```
app.post('/review', function(req, res){
  req.session.name = req.body.name;
  res.render('review.njk', { name: req.body.name });
});
```

and on Page2, I'm using another `<form method="POST" action="/send">` and on `submit` of this form, I'm taking the data from the session and calling a POST request.

```
app.post('/send', function(req, res){
  // POST using req.session.name as request data
});
```

**My concern:**

- I have lot of fields on a single form and lots of pages with forms and don't want to have a session management overhead (deleting data from session on each success call etc).
- Also using the second forms for this purpose seems unorthodox to me. The purpose of the second "fake" form is only to pass through the data to the second route. Alternatively, you can have 10 hidden form inputs having the values of the collected data along with 10 elements to display the review data and then on `submit`, send them to the backend. In both cases, it seems sort of unclean in my opinion.

So, my questions is - Using Express (and no AJAX), Is there a better way to do this (collect the form data from first page, show it on the next page and then submit the data) ?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can make generic component for two step form submit. There is given number of input types so also limited variants how can be represented in review step

Comment: @bigless - Could you elaborate a little on it please ?

Comment: Create class which constructor takes form element and dynamically creates review block based on inputs. Class is statefull so you can easily handle back/next.

Comment: Oh I get it.. Thanks for the suggestion. Could you suggest anything to do with the data. As in store in session, avoid another form etc ?

Comment: Then you dont need session because its one page. If you want to fill form with data from last session(f.e. accidentaly closed tab etc), you can save data to session/local/cookie storage on client side. All could be handled with mentioned component.